# Stopping a System.Timers.Timer

Tags: c#, timer

Let's say I have this code

```
public static Timer timer;

static void Main ()
{
    timer = new Timer ( 60 * 1000 );   // It ticks every minute
    timer.Elpased += One;
    timer.Elapsed += Two;
}

private static void One ( sender o, EventArgs e )
{
    timer.Stop ();
}

private static void Two ( sender o, EventArgs e )
{
    DoSomething ();
}
```

Since I'm assuming that 'One' and 'Two' will execute in subscribe order, stopping the Timer in 'One' will prevent 'Two' from happening?

If not, how can I do it?

Comment: check the timer state in Two

Comment: When you call `timer.Elapsed -= One` then `Two` will still be executing, as it removes the delegate of `One` but not running the code within it when that happens.

Comment: @EdgarsŠturms Yeah but calling timer.Elapsed -= Two on One won't stop Two from executing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Threading.Timer` does not have an `Elapsed` event. It requires a single `TimerCallback` delegate passed to the constructor, which it executes on a `ThreadPool` thread.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

I believe you are looking at `System.Timers.Timer`, which does have an `Elapsed` event.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

I do not believe there is a way to guarantee a way to prevent `Two` from firing the way you describe.  You must assume that `One` and `Two` execute at the exact same time on 2 different threads.  Even calling `Stop()` isn't guaranteed to prevent the timer from firing an additional time: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.stop(v=vs.110).aspx.

My suggestion would be to have a single callback that handles the branching logic on if it should perform the actions in `Two` after the logic in `One` executes.

Comment: Yeah I missed that, I was using System.Timers ( already edited ), also I think that branching the logic is my best approach, I just thought there could be a way to prevent it. Anyways ty